# Handling missing values in a database schema?

Tags: database-design, modeling, missing-data, representation

Suppose I have the following table schema

```
MONTH VARCHAR(10)
HASRAIN BOOLEAN
YEAR INTEGER
```

Now suppose for a particular year, I have values for 11 months, but no value for the the left over month (let's call it September).

Is it more correct to:

1. Put a record in with a zero value, or
2. Leave no record for that month

My question is: **How do you model the absence of information in a database schema?**

Comment: Null or no record - if you added a zero value, how could you tell the difference between "It didn't rain at all" and "I don't know how much it rained"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If information about an entity is not needed to understand another entity, these are not cognitively dependant on each other and can be normalised.

What this means in general practice is that you should make separate tables for the two entities and use foreign keys to refer between them.

Imagine this:

```
Table weather_month:
------------
month ENUM('Jan', 'Feb', Mar' ...) NOT NULL,
year mediumint NOT NULL,
weather_id mediumint,
PRIMARY KEY(month, year)

Table weather:
------------
weather_id mediumint NOT NULL
rain BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
clouds ENUM('Clear', 'Sparse', 'Thick', 'Cumulus', ...) NOT NULL,
temperature ENUM('Freezing', 'Thawing', 'T-shirt weather', 'Hot', ...) NOT NULL
```

This example shows how we either know what the weather is, or we don't.

If you would put lots and lots of nullable fields into the weather_month table (as is quite a quite common way of doing this), it would not be as clear as in this setup that you have either observed the weather or you did not.

Relational databases use NULL for "I have no value", but you should really consider how you use it, because the database design you make should speak for your data structure and if it speaks for itself, you won't have to explain it to people. Saves you time.

Answer (score 0):

NULL may be more appropriate in terms of storage efficiency especially if you expect most of them will have no value. Otherwise, depending on your business requirement, 0 may do as well.

Also, you may need consider how easy to query it with no records. Say in a particular year, you have some months with no value. If you keep them in table w 0/NULL on a particular column, aggregating it will be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like two tables to me:

```
CALENDAR
+----+-----+
|YEAR|MONTH|
+----+-----+

WEATHER
+----+-----+-------+
|YEAR|MONTH|HASRAIN|
+----+-----+-------+
```

All months would be included in the CALENDAR table. Only the months with weather information would be included in the WEATHER table.